# Disable "Spring Effect" when scrolling over the maximum limit

Tags: macos

I'm not sure if this is a global OS X setting or per-app implementation of an Apple API. Anyway, is it possible (specifically on Google Chrome) to disable that visual "spring effect" (I don't know how to call it) that we have on Mavericks when scrolling up/down or swipe right/left and we reach the boundaries of the page?

I mean this one:

[image]

Comment: I do not believe so. It's intended as visual feedback that you have reached an edge of the scrollable area.

Comment: It seems to interfere with my custom gesture (bettertouchtools) when I swipe left/right with two fingers. It shows me this effect when in fact I want to have another behavior

Answer (score 2):

In the past, it was possible to disable the so-called *rubber band* effect by using this little command in terminal:

```
defaults write -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding -int 0
```

To revert the changes you used:

```
defaults delete -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding
```

You need to restart the apps to see the changes (or reboot the whole system).

Alas, I am no longer sure if it works. I tried it on Yosemite, but it seems to be obsolete now. Worth giving a shot, though!

Answer (score 0):

The option is in accessibility settings. You don't need to use the terminal.
There's a post about it here:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1200918

Comment: Hi Welcome to AskDiffernt, you may want to summarise the link you posted, that way if the link ever stops working your answer still stands alone.

Comment: This isn't quite the same thing. The option in accessibility lets you toggle "inertia", which affects whether scrolling continues after the relevant input (double-fingered swipe on a touchpad) stops. If inertia is turned off, but you are at the top or bottom of a page in a browser, it will still "scroll past the end of the page" as long as you are actively swiping up/down.